# Combing multiple .removeAttr() statements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple `removeAttr()` is there a way I can combine them?

**What I have:** (this works)

```
checkboxes.removeAttr("checked",'checked');
checkboxes.removeAttr("indeterminate", false);
checkboxes.removeAttr("role", 'checkbox');
checkboxes.removeAttr("aria-checked", false);
```

**What I have tried:** (this doesn't work)

```
checkboxes.removeAttr({
    checked: 'checked',
    indeterminate: false,
    role: 'checkbox',
    'aria-checked': false
});
```

When I try this I get the following console error. So either my syntax is wrong or this just doesn't work.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'toLowerCase'  jquery.min.js:2
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: [`.removeAttr()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) only takes one parameter.  `An attribute to remove; as of version 1.7, it can be a space-separated list of attributes.`

Comment: Aren't you really looking for `.prop()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `$.each` with an array, quick, short, and expandable.

```
$.each(["checked","indeterminate"],function(i,attrName){
    checkbox.removeAttr(attrName);
});
```

Comment: this is a best way.. 
this will help in no need to repeat the code 
.removeAttr() every time..

Answer (score 3):

According to ***[removeAttr()](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)*** doc it does not accept an object. so

`checkboxes.removeAttr({});` will not work. and it also accept one paremeter [thx @RocketHazmat] for correction to which you want to remove.

You can do a chaining like:

```
checkboxes
   .removeAttr("checked")
   .removeAttr("indeterminate")
   .removeAttr("role")
   .removeAttr("aria-checked");
```

But if  you want to set attribute then you've to use `attr()` method like:

```
checkboxes
  .attr("checked", 'checked')
  .attr("indeterminate",false )
  .attr("role",'checkbox')
  .attr("aria-checked", false);
```

Comment: `removeAttr` only takes one parameter, not two.

Comment: @PuzzledBoy was a bad mistake... sorry for that :(

Comment: Thanks for explaining this to me better. However I like Kevin B's approach and will accept that as my answer.

Comment: @japanFour thx a lot... and im happy with that... coz #Kevin is best among all threads, i think.

Comment: @Jeremy T, True, that is why I assumed I could do the same with `removeAttr()`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're passing both keys and values to `removeAttr`, but if you just want to remove those 4 attributes from an element, pass a space-separated list of the keys, like so:

```
checkboxes.removeAttr("checked indeterminate role aria-checked");
```

Comment: Right, if you're using an older version of jQuery you'd need to use the method described by thecodeparadox

Answer (score 1):

@RocketHazmat is right, so it would be like this:

```
checkboxes.removeAttr("checked indeterminate role aria-checked");
```

But you need 1.7 or later from jQuery.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Sorry for the mistype.

Comment: Don't worry about it.  It's fine :-)